# how use Quality selection for Videogular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, videogular

I use [videogular](https://github.com/videogular/videogular) to display the video.
and [noppolp](https://github.com/noppolp/videogular-quality)
When I put the code into a normal state, the video runs
But the code does not execute when I set up a multi-quality code.